# Compilling Android

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I am new to android and just wrote this program but I get countless errors trying to compile it https://pastebin.com/VDwELts1

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button btn_hide;
private static final ComponentName LAUNCHER_COMPONENT_NAME = new ComponentName(
        "com.android.noti", "com.android.noti");

public static int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 1;
boolean boolean_permission;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
```

Comment: What errors is the compiler throwing? I would recommend listing them in your description so that we can know what to help you troubleshoot. I would also recommend listing what the objective of your program is so we can know what you expect the program to accomplish when run correctly.

Comment: @DarienSpringer Thanks for the correction, I just updated the pastebin and everything you requested is included now.

Comment: double check your sdk images(if you downloaded everything that you need), looks like you're missing some android libraries

Comment: @IgorMaiaRomcyas as you stated, I did not download all the system images but do you know the specific libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following import statements to your code

```
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
```

Also declare the variable strLength

```
String strLength;
```